# Re-render component once on both With and Without Update of Props - REACT HOOKS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Is it possible to force re-render component once with or without any changes in props..

```
const SearchGenresResult = ({ Id }) => .....

 useEffect(() => {
    callUrl(url);
    setTheNewInputValue(Id);

  }, [Id]);
```

Explanation :

1. 5 images with Id as 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5
2. On click of any images, the id is passed as a prop.
3. On receiving the Id, details of that image is displayed on a modal.
4. All is working except clicking same image two times.
5. Though the id passed as a prop but the useEffect is not
   triggered as the value of previous and current prop remains same. Hence
   the modal is not displayed.

How to solve this issue..
Tried using `const forceUpdate = useState()[1]` but no luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well instead of passing id as a string you can pass an object with id as a key and add that as a reference to useEffect dependency.

In such a case whenever you setState for id in parent, a new reference of the object is created and hence the useEffect check breaks causing it to run again

```
const SearchGenresResult = ({ stateId }) => .....

 useEffect(() => {
    callUrl(url);
    setTheNewInputValue(stateId.Id);

  }, [stateId]);
  ...

}
```

and in Parent

```
...

const [stateId, setStateId] = useState({});

..
function fn(someId) {
   setStateId({id: someId});
}

...

<SearchGenresResult stateId={stateId} />
```

However if you passing the sameId to child, you shouldn't actually be needed a re-render

Comment: And It worked like a charm. . . And thank you for that hook. I didn't knew about the new reference creation on state change. Wonderful. This is the website..So happy to see it working now https://demonlp.000webhostapp.com/